# how to add minicart in custom header block in magento2

Tags: magento2, theme, custom, header, mini-cart

i have created block in theme in magento2.
block location is "***theme-folder/template/html/header.phtml***".
i want to add minicart in this Phtml file.

Comment: you can extend by refferenceBlock of "minicart", check with Template Path Hint

Answer (score 8):

Not Tried but you can add directly in `phtml` with below code

```
<?php  echo $this->getLayout()
          ->createBlock('Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Sidebar')
          ->setTemplate('Magento_Checkout::cart/minicart.phtml')
          ->toHtml(); ?>
```

Comment: It worked for me . Voted up response.

Comment: @Qaisar Satti I need to add form.mini.phtml from search module. how can I do it? I have seperate header for mobile view and I need to display minicart when I click on icon I put as cart(custom inage as icon). please help

Comment: @Qaisar Satti I added your code in header but it seems that content is not rendering properly in minicart popup so do you have any solution for this?

Answer (score 4):

Yes. Adding

```
<?php  echo $this->getLayout()
          ->createBlock('Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Sidebar')
          ->setTemplate('Magento_Checkout::cart/minicart.phtml')
          ->toHtml(); ?>
```

to header.phtml works

Comment: thanks man... 
can you please tell me how can we add block from another modules..??

Comment: I hope you already done this but want to update community that above code can be added in any custom phtml file and minicart will display there.